# Obtaining Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS) with JumP - Julia

Tags: julia, linear-programming, gurobi, julia-jump

I am trying to obtain the constraints that are included in the IIS, for example with the following infeasible problem

```
using JuMP, Gurobi
model = direct_model(Gurobi.Optimizer())

# defining variables
@variable(model, z)
@variable(model, x1[a=1:10, b=1:5] => 0)
@variable(model, x2[a=1:10, b=1:5, c=1:7] => 0)
# and so on...

# objective and constraints

@objective(model, Max, z)

@constraint(model, const1[a=1:10, b=1:5, c=1:7], equation1)
@constraint(model, const2[b=1:5, c=1:7], equation2)
# and so on...

optimize!(model)

if termination_status(model) == MOI.INFEASIBLE_OR_UNBOUNDED
    @assert termination_status(model) == MOI.INFEASIBLE_OR_UNBOUNDED
    compute_conflict!(model)
    MOI.get(model, MOI.ConstraintConflictStatus(), const1)
end
```

However, it always returns an error of

```
MethodError: no method matching get(::Model, ::MathOptInterface.ConstraintConflictStatus, ::Array{ConstraintRef{Model,MathOptInterface.ConstraintIndex{MathOptInterface.ScalarAffineFunction{Float64},MathOptInterface.EqualTo{Float64}},ScalarShape},3})
```

Am I doing this correctly?

I am using JuliaPro_v1.53-1, JuMP v0.21.6, Gurobi v0.9.11

Any bits of help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on the community forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/obtaining-irreducible-inconsistent-subsystem-iis-with-jump-gurobi/58491/2

`const1` is an array. Use broadcasting:

```
MOI.get.(model, MOI.ConstraintConflictStatus(), const1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and solution!

Answer (score 0):

For quick inspection, you can also print the IIS to a file as follows:

```
using JuMP
using Gurobi
GRBwrite(JuMP.backend(model), "conflict.ilp")
```